# Node.js fs.writeFile() doesn't seem asynchronous

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, file-writing

If we head over to the documentation of Node.js for the [`fs.writeFile()` method](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback), we see that it is asynchronous in nature.

Now, with that in mind, I set up the following code to test this idea:

```
const fs = require('fs');

function sync(delay) {
    const startingTime = new Date();
    while ((new Date() - startingTime) < delay) {
        // keep this loop going
    }
}


fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/hello.txt', 'Hello World', function() {});

sync(4000);
```

I have opened the `hello.txt` file in VSCode, and whenever some data is written to the file, VSCode shows it live.

I expect this code to write *Hello World* to the file `hello.txt`, before 4 seconds (which is the delay caused by `sync(4000)`) since `fs.writeFile()` is asynchronous in nature (as the documentation says). However, to my surprise, any data is written to the file *after* 4 seconds.

This doesn't seem asynchronous at all!

My question is, why isn't the data written to the file `hello.txt` before the synchronous execution of the whole script.

I suspect (btw, I don't know much about OS threads) that when `fs.writeFile()` is called, it writes to the file asynchronously (without blocking the main thread) on another OS thread that is free, but this doesn't seem to happen.

I have been testing quite a lot other things related to file-write utilities, such as Writable streams and have seen the same issue. Nothing is written unless and until all of the synchronous execution completes.

I need a clear explanation on this kind-of internal thing.

Comment: And what happens when you write to the file from within `setTimeout` function?

Comment: @vanowm Same result.

Comment: and if you execute `sync` from `setTimeout`?

Comment: @vanowm I don't get what you mean.

Comment: `setTimeout(sync(4000));`

Comment: @vanowm, even before I do this, I can reason that it isn't what I am trying to explore. If I run this, then there won't be any synchronous delay since I have encapsulated `sync()` inside a `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import { writeFile } from 'fs/promises'

function sync(delay) {
  const startingTime = new Date();
  while ((new Date() - startingTime) < delay) {
      // keep this loop going
  }
}

(async () => {
  await writeFile(__dirname + '/hello.txt', 'Hello World');

  sync(4000)
})();
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I want to understand what's causing the above code to write after 4 seconds, not how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Although `writeFile` may seem asynchronous in behavior, NodeJS is limited by the fact that JavaScript is a single-threaded language. To simulate being asynchronous, NodeJS uses the [event loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) in order to process actions.

I'm not sure exactly on the inner workings of the `writeFile` function, but judging from how the code runs it can be assumed that 3 or more tasks are being added to the event loop (one for creating the file, one for writing to the created file, and one for processing the callback). The multiple events are important to understanding why the code executes the way it does.

When the `writeFile` function call executes, the 'hello.txt' file is generated empty (creating the file, the first task). However, since the `writeFile` call was executed, the JavaScript engine has already moved on and executed the culprit of the problem, your `sync` function. The `sync` function utilizing a `while` loop to simulate a delay rather than the normally used `setTimeout` function is key to understanding what is going on internally.

What the while loop is doing in this scenario is hijacking the event loop before writing to the file that was created (which explains why the file is created but not written to) due to `while` being a blocking operation. You can verify this behavior by adding another I/O operation using `writeFileSync` before your `sync` function. Both files will be created but only the `writeFileSync` function's file would have anything written in it.

Due to the `while` loop blocking the event loop, the data is written to the file after your delay because that is when the `while` loop finishes executing and frees up the event loop in order to execute the final tasks of the `writeFile` function.

Note: This answer was written with a degree of uncertainty as I haven't explored the internals of how the NodeJS event loop works thoroughly. The documents I referenced in answering this question are here:

- [Don't Block The Event Loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/)
- [Overview of Blocking vs Non-Blocking](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/)
- [The Node.js Event Loop](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-nodejs-event-loop)

Comment: I am still not clear. What you are saying is that the event loop is blocked and so the write operation (i.e. the `write()` method) doesn't execute. But I think that when `write()` is called it could create a file writing process (asynchronously in the background) on a free thread which could then do the writing (this is happening in the background, NOT synchronously) — why is it the case that the program has to wait all 4 seconds before writing.

Comment: @coderboy How the writing to the file is implemented in this scenario doesn't matter, as your `while` is blocking the writing from occurring in the first place. Moving the question from "why does it wait" to "why does it wait when it could" is a design philosophy question that I can't answer, but keep in mind that NodeJS isn't like other languages where logic like this would work, as NodeJS is based on the philosophy of [event-driven programming](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_event_loop.htm).

Comment: The main thread in which Node is running is blocked by the `sync()` call, and this is the only thread allotted to run JavaScript code. The file writing internally shouldn't be happening in here. That's what I am trying to emphasize. There are usually other threads available when executing JavaScript async stuff internally where all the async magic happens. I want to know why is the file writing not happening in this separate thread, that is NOT affected by the main thread's synchronous delay.

Comment: I suspect (but once again I am not sure because I don't know C++ and digging into the internals of Node.js from ground up takes a lot time) that the file writing is prevented so that the program could *gather* data from *all* calls to `write()` in the program in one single place (typically, a buffer) and then write *all of that data at once*, rather than writing each data one-by-one. I just want some Node geek to confirm or maybe correct me on this...

Comment: @coderboy Unfortunately I'm not exactly certain on why writing is delayed, but the file writing itself is definitely being prevented by the `sync()`. Writing itself is asynchronous (see: [Worker Pool](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/)).